# Why tcpdump has 262144 as default capture size?

Tags: tcpdump

I was wondering for the reason that why tcpdump has magic number `262144` as default snapshot length?

> --snapshot-length=snaplen
>       Snarf snaplen bytes of data from each packet rather than the default of 262144 bytes. Packets truncated because of a limited
>   snapshot are indicated in the output with ``[|proto]'', where proto is
>   the name of the protocol level at which the truncation has occurred. 
>       Note that taking larger snapshots both increases the amount of time it takes to process packets and, effectively, decreases the
>   amount of packet buffering. This may cause packets to be lost. Note
>   also that taking smaller snapshots will discard data from protocols
>   above the transport layer, which loses information that may be
>   important. NFS and AFS requests and replies, for example, are very
>   large, and much of the detail won't be available if a too-short
>   snapshot length is selected. 
>       If you need to reduce the snapshot size below the default, you should limit snaplen to the smallest number that will capture the
>   protocol information you're interested in. Setting snaplen to 0 sets
>   it to the default of 262144, for backwards compatibility with recent
>   older versions of tcpdump.

Reference: [man page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/tcpdump-4.9/netdissect.h

```
/*
 * Maximum snapshot length.  This should be enough to capture the full
 * packet on most network interfaces.
 *
 *
 * Somewhat arbitrary, but chosen to be:
 *
 *    1) big enough for maximum-size Linux loopback packets (65549)
 *       and some USB packets captured with USBPcap:
 *
 *           http://desowin.org/usbpcap/
 *
 *       (> 131072, < 262144)
 *
 * and
 *
 *    2) small enough not to cause attempts to allocate huge amounts of
 *       memory; some applications might use the snapshot length in a
 *       savefile header to control the size of the buffer they allocate,
 *       so a size of, say, 2^31-1 might not work well.
 *
 * XXX - does it need to be bigger still?
 */
#define MAXIMUM_SNAPLEN 262144
```

Not a lot to it. Linux loopback is unbounded by hardware frames and so has a fairly large max size at 64k. Other packets can be even larger, so up a couple powers of two to 256k.